# Layers not correctly generated using SAGA algorithms within QGIS 3.4.4-Madeira

Tags: qgis, saga

I am trying to use a few algorithms that may be useful for my work, that are part of the processing tools packaged with the latest LTR 64-bit version of QGIS in Windows 10 64 bit.. However, all of the SAGA algorithms that I have tried so far throw the same final error, regarding layers that were not correctly generated. The following image is the end of the log message I get. In red is the error I mention. It happens with all tools I have tried so far.

[image: Log capture]

I checked other posts and read similar issues. Some suggestions to fix it included using different paths, and avoiding blank spaces in them.
I tried changing the path to a D:\Temp directory but no success.

Things I noticed:

- In the log, some paths appear with forward slash (/), as in Unix systems.
- Some long paths appear shortened, using the tilde (~). In particular, C:\OSGeo4W64 gets shortened to C:\OSGeo4~1

Any hints?

**EDIT:**

This is the output log provided in comments:

```
Procesando algoritmo...

Algoritmo 'Profiles from lines' comenzando…

Parámetros de entrada:

{ 'DEM' : 'F:/Dropbox/QGIS_Test/DEM.tif', 'LINES' : 'F:\\Dropbox\\QGIS_Test\\Lines.shp', 'NAME' : 'id', 'PROFILE' : 'C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/8d34e08d5a984c11a8ffce8b99fadd36/PROFILE.shp', 'PROFILES' : 'C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp', 'SPLIT ' : True, 'VALUES' : '' }


io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/635ead2d3ee34f7bbeda0d5905c407b0/DEM.sgrd" -FILES "F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\DEM.tif"

ta_profiles "Profiles from Lines" -DEM "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/635ead2d3ee34f7bbeda0d5905c407b0/DEM.sgrd" -LINES "F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\Lines.shp" -NAME "id" -SPLIT true -PROFILE "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/8d34e08d5a984c11a8ffce8b99fadd36/PROFILE.shp" -PROFILES "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp"


F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr


F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr\modules


F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qt5\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr\modules


F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/635ead2d3ee34f7bbeda0d5905c407b0/DEM.sgrd" -FILES "F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\DEM.tif"

____________________________


##### ## ##### ##

### ### ## ###

### # ## ## #### # ##

### ##### ## # #####

##### # ## ##### # ##

____________________________


SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (32 bit)


____________________________

library path: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\saga-ltr\modules\

library name: io_gdal

library : GDAL/OGR

tool : Import Raster

author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)

processors : 8 [8]

____________________________




Parameters



Grids: No objects

Files: "F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\DEM.tif"

Select from Multiple Bands:

Alphanumeric Sorting: yes

Transformation: yes

Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation



loading: F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\DEM.tif




Driver: GTiff


Bands: 1


Rows: 5557


Columns: 7445



loading: DEM






F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>saga_cmd ta_profiles "Profiles from Lines" -DEM "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/635ead2d3ee34f7bbeda0d5905c407b0/DEM.sgrd" -LINES "F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\Lines.shp" -NAME "id" -SPLIT true -PROFILE "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/8d34e08d5a984c11a8ffce8b99fadd36/PROFILE.shp" -PROFILES "C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp"

Error: dbf write: invalid table

____________________________


##### ## ##### ##

### ### ## ###

### # ## ## #### # ##

### ##### ## # #####

##### # ## ##### # ##

____________________________


SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (32 bit)


____________________________

library path: C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.4\apps\saga-ltr\modules\

library name: ta_profiles

library : Profiles

tool : Profiles from Lines

author : O.Conrad (c) 2006

processors : 8 [8]

____________________________


Load grid: C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/635ead2d3ee34f7bbeda0d5905c407b0/DEM.sgrd...



Load shapes: F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test\Lines.shp...





Parameters



Grid system: 5; 5557x 7445y; 511960x 4649730y

DEM: DEM

Values: No objects

Lines: Lines

Name: id

Profiles: Profiles

Profiles: No objects

Each Line as new Profile: yes




failed

Save shapes: C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp_1...



Save shapes: C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp_2...




F:\Dropbox\QGIS_Test>exit

Ejecución completada en 12.90 segundos

Resultados:

{'PROFILE': 'C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/8d34e08d5a984c11a8ffce8b99fadd36/PROFILE.shp',
'PROFILES': 'C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/acbe581a52b9406fb5db4af3292f919a/PROFILES.shp'}


Cargando las capas resultantes

Las siguientes capas no se generaron correctamente.<ul><li>C:/Users/Kais/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_5080f69b88474281943ae5c46597245d/8d34e08d5a984c11a8ffce8b99fadd36/PROFILE.shp</li></ul>Puede comprobar el «Panel de mensajes del registro» en la ventana principal de QGIS para encontrar más información sobre la ejecución del algoritmo.
```

Comment: What happens if you _Save to File..._ instead of _Save to a temporary file_ for the outputs?

Comment: Could you also change the folder name `bati 2018 10 03` to something without spaces, and try again?

Comment: Unfortunately none of those options, saving to a named file with a short path, or substituting the spaces with a "_" produced any difference. Anyone can provide a project that works in their system to check mine?

Comment: There is no problem with the forward slash nor with the tilde in paths. But your screnshot doesn't look like the latest version of `qgis` and `saga-ltr` packages provided by OSGeo4W. Please, include wich version of both packages are you running. And include the log output as fornatted text instead of the screenshot. Also, we can test the _Profile from lines_ tool with your data if you provide a raster layer and a vector layer with at least one line to extract the profile. But if you can't run any SAGA algorithhm in QGIS, the problem would not be the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GabrielDeLuca. I am running QGIS 3.4.4-Madeira. The saga tools I am using are 2.3.2 (this is the floating text tip that appears when I hover with the mouse pointer on the SAGA logo in the Process Toolbox.

Comment: I can´t paste the log here in a comment. I could edit the post but maybe it becomes cluttered and unreadable. Also, I have a project with a raster DEM and a vector layer with two lines that does not work. I am unsure how to share it here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To know the version of the packages, run the OSGeo4W setup tool in advanced mode and search that libraries in the installed packages view. To include the log in the body of the cuestion, include it between code snippet lines (````). To share data, you need to upload somewhere (google drive or dropbox are good options) and share the link to download.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca thanks for the tips. I checked with the setup tool and versions are qgis 3.4.4-1, saga-ltr 2.3.2-4. I prepared and example that does not work completely on my system. It created one profile from one of the two lines. The other line gave the same error, of layers not generated correctly. If you can test it, the files are in [link] (https://bit.ly/2NcAq9r). The log output of the _Profiles from lines_ is too long to include it here in a comment. I saved it in the same folder as html, to keep the formatting. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The log output attached is from another QGIS (a stand-alone version) than the log in the screenshot of your question. Uncheck the "Each Line as New Profile" option. I can't undestand how this algorithm work, but it can create just one profile output. Unchecking that option, all lines are considered as one profile. Then you can select or extract each profile from the "LINE_ID" column of the attribute table.

Comment: I just add an answer for the Profile to Lines tool. For other tools please open specific questions. I will propose an edit to your post including the log provided in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some problems with the *Profiles from lines* algorithm in QGIS.

Let's see first how it should work.

In SAGA GIS, at the command line:

- If you want to save *Each Line as a New Profile*, you need to use the `-SPLIT` and the `-PROFILES` options. Files will be saved as *profile_01.shp*, *profile_02.shp*, etc.
- If not, don't use `-SPLIT` option and use `-PROFILE` option. File will be saved as *profile.shp*.

In QGIS processing toolbox:

- Both `-PROFILE` and `-PROFILES` options are always used, so one of them always returns an error (The following layers were not correctly generated.).
- If you tick on *Each Line as a New Profile* (is ticked by default), `-SPLIT` option is used, and the files are saved as *PROFILE.shp1*, *PROFILE.shp2*, etc. That produced two errors (one for the `-PROFILE` empty layer and other for the invalid extensions).

A bug report was already opened: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21294.

Meanwhile, a possible workaround is to not use the *Each Line as a New Profile* option (untick it) and ignore the error generated by the `-PROFILE` over option.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielDeLuca. Very informative answer.